# Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: operator does not exist: jsonb #> text

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql

I have the following SQL query:

```
select distinct "Customers"."CustomerId"        as "CustomerId",
                "Customers"."FcmRegistrationId" as "FcmRegistrationId",
                "Customers"."FCMServerKey"      as "FCMServerKey",
                "Customers"."AppId"             as "AppId"
from "CustomerEvents"
         inner join "Customers" on "CustomerEvents"."CustomerId" = "Customers"."CustomerId"
where  "Customers"."AdvertiserId" = 16 and "Data" #> '{inner_id}' = '4249699';
```

It works nice in my SQL-editor-client (DataGrip). But when I use it with `C#` and I have the error from the title of this question.

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: operator does not exist: jsonb #> text

I will show you my code:

```
public class PartnerApiServices : IPartnerApiService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;

    public PartnerApiServices(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
    {
        _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
    }

    public IQueryable<CustomerForPartnerApiServiceModel> GetCustomerBySearchField(Advertiser advertiser, string searchValue)
    {
        var rawSql = @"
            select distinct ""Customers"".""CustomerId""        as ""CustomerId"",
                            ""Customers"".""FcmRegistrationId"" as ""FcmRegistrationId"",
                            ""Customers"".""FCMServerKey""      as ""FCMServerKey"",
                            ""Customers"".""AppId""             as ""AppId""
            from ""CustomerEvents""
                     inner join ""Customers"" on ""CustomerEvents"".""CustomerId"" = ""Customers"".""CustomerId""
            where  ""Customers"".""AdvertiserId"" = @AdvertiserId and ""Data"" #> @SearchField = @SearchValue"; 

        var res = _applicationDbContext.BySearchFieldCustomerApiModels.FromSql(rawSql,
            new NpgsqlParameter("SearchField", advertiser.SearchField),
            new NpgsqlParameter("SearchValue", searchValue),
            new NpgsqlParameter<int>("AdvertiserId", advertiser.AdvertiserId));

        return res;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how I can pass `SearchField` and `SearchValue` correctly?

Comment: @mjwills  `advertiser.SearchField` dump is string like `{"inner_id"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an explicit type cast so that PostgreSQL knows that the string literal is to be interpreted as array:

```cs
var rawSql = @"
            ...
            where  ""Data"" #>> CAST(@SearchField AS text[]) = @SearchValue";
```

Comment: Sorry, but this update gives me new error `Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: operator does not exist: jsonb = text`.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `#>>` rather than `#>`, like Shay Rojansky wrote. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

To use a text parameter, instead of using `#>` use `#>>`. The former expects a `jsonb` parameter, whereas the latter expects a `text` parameter ([see the PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)).

The reason your code works in DataGrip is that `'{inner_id}'` is an untyped literal embedded directly in your SQL, so PostgreSQL implicitly casts it to `jsonb`. However, when using a parameter with Npgsql, Npgsql sends a typed `text` parameter (Npgsql's parameters are (almost) always typed)), and so PostgreSQL complains about the mismatch.

Comment: What do you think about compare with text, not `jsonb`?  I heard that it's not very good idea. Because jsonb has own compressed format and comparison with text may gives wrong result. Or `#>>` saves situation?

Comment: @Shay Rojansky This answer gives me new error.  `Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: operator does not exist: jsonb #>> text`